# Combine list array data and send to jqplot

Tags: c#, json, arraylist, jqplot

I currently have two list arrays which i would like to combine into a single list array (which will then be sent client side via js for use with jqplot).

Here are the two list array's first of all, - with some test data which will later be replaced by something from a database

```
List<int> xValues = new List<int>() { 4, 7, 11, 12, 20, 22, 28, 27, 20 };
List<int> yValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Now, what i would like to do initially is convert the data into a format similar to this "[[4,1],[7,2],[11,3],[12,4],[20,5]..... [20,9]]"

Then send that data client side to jqplot.

I tried a method earlier today which involved using stringbuilder to combine the data, save it as a variable and inject it clientside using response.write, however I felt that this wasn't the right way to go.

If anyone could help that would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a list of lists (i.e., `List<List<int>>`), I think the easiest way would be to leverage the `IEnumerable.Zip()` method to stitch the two lists into one list of lists.